# SwiftUI animation fails when nested in VStack

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

Trying to animate sub-views that are nested in a VStack hierarchy. In the example below, why do the views in the outer VStack animate correctly, but the views nested one level deeper do not?

Seems like the inner VStack is completely erasing/hiding the animations attached to those subviews.

```
struct SampleView: View {
@State private var showDetails = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Press to show details") {
            withAnimation {
                showDetails.toggle()
            }
        }

        if showDetails {
            
            VStack {
                // These views embedded in the sub-VStack do not animate at all:
                Text("Incorrect 1")
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(0)))
                Text("Incorrect 2")
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(1)))
                Text("Incorrect 3")
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(2)))
            }
            
            // These views animate correctly:
            Text("Correct 1")
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(0)))
            Text("Correct 2")
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(1)))
            Text("Correct 3")
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(2)))

        } else {
            Text("Waiting for details")
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image: Animation example image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's because the whole VStack is inserted as one view at once. But you can move the `if` inside the Stack and add a second one like this, then it works:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Press to show details") {
            withAnimation {
                showDetails.toggle()
            }
        }
        
        VStack {
            if showDetails {
                // These views embedded in the sub-VStack do not animate at all:
                Text("Incorrect 1")
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(0)))
                Text("Incorrect 2")
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(1)))
                Text("Incorrect 3")
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(2)))
            }
        }
        if showDetails {
            // These views animate correctly:
            Text("Correct 1")
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(0)))
            Text("Correct 2")
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(1)))
            Text("Correct 3")
                .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(2)))
            
        } else {
            Text("Waiting for details")
        }
    }
    .transition(.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(2)))
```

}

Comment: Yeah this works, but do you agree we shouldn't need this workaround? The Text views are still being inserted into the hierarchy so they should get their own transitions. Also it makes the view a bit messier with repeated if statements.

Comment: In your version the whole VStack is toggled, but has different transitions inside it. I suppose Swift can't handle that.  If you give the whole VStack only one transition, it does work.  But I agree – it would be better if it could :)